# Not loading module "atk-bridge": The functionality is provided by GTK natively. Please try to not load it

Tags: linux, ubuntu, proxy, proxychains

Keep getting this error.

Not loading module "atk-bridge": The functionality is provided by GTK natively. Please try to not load it.

I ran
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libcanberra-gtk-module
sudo apt install libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk3-module

and still cant get it to run. Trying to configure proxychain.

Comment: welcome to SO. which command can you execute to provoke this diagnostic message? this would be useful to have in your question so that there is more context and a reproducible example. also the ubuntu version. please [edit] in all the details.

Comment: I see this same error in Ubuntu 22.04 over and over as well.  `snapd-desktop-i` keeps emitting it.  I do have libcanberra installed.  I am *not* logged in via the UI when these messages show up in the logs.  The screen on that system is asleep.  (I'm ssh'd in.)

Answer (score 5):

To get rid of the message

> Not loading module "atk-bridge": The functionality is provided by GTK natively. Please try to not load it.

I removed the libatk-adaptor package (I'm on Ubuntu 22.04).

```
sudo apt purge libatk-adaptor
sudo reboot
```

Note that `atk` stands for Accessibility Toolkit, which I don't use.
Judging from the error message GTK has this builtin. So it can probably be removed safely.

The package modifies the environment variable `GTK_MODULES`. Adding `gail:atk-bridge`.

Therefor as a temporary solution - prevent reboot -, you might remove the `gail:atk-bridge` part from GTK_MODULES.

When gail:atk-bridge is the only text in GTK_MODULES, just do:

```
unset GTK_MODULES
```

Though that would be temporary and only effect the current shell.

To effect only one program's run, e.g. firefox, do:

```
GTK_MODULES= firefox
```

Comment: thank you, it's useful (I'll just add that 'apt remove' was not enough in my case, so with 'dpkg --purge libatk-adaptor' I got rid of those libatk artefacts)

Comment: I changed the 'apt remove' into 'apt purge'. That will get rid of libatk-adaptor's configuration.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same Error, my case was reported by "snapd-desktop-integration",and this issue got fixed after I upgrade snapd-desktop-integration to latest version.

If your case was also reported by "snapd-desktop-integration", please try to upgrade it to newer version as:

```
sudo snap refresh snapd-desktop-integration --stable
```